# jquery :input filter works different in chrome than ie/edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an event that checks to see if something has changed on my form. The following filter will return all inputs as well as select fields in Chrome. In IE/Edge the filter only returns inputs excluding selects. Can anyone explain why and what a good solution would be?

```
$('.form-observer').filter(':input').off("input").on('input', function (e, args)
{
    //Breaks here when a textbox or select box changes when using chrome
    ...
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Hey Maxqueue, were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: So looks like a bug in jquery. Had to add filter on select as well which is now working.